# Deploy Foundation for Apps on Heroku

Tags: heroku, gulp, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

I am trying to deploy an app created with "Foundation for Apps" on Heroku with no success.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "foundation-apps-template",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.7.9",
    "front-matter": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "^0.7.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.2.8",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "through2": "^0.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.7.9",
    "front-matter": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "^0.7.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.2.8",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "through2": "^0.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
// FOUNDATION FOR APPS TEMPLATE GULPFILE
// -------------------------------------
// This file processes all of the assets in the "client" folder, combines them with the Foundation
// for Apps assets, and outputs the finished files in the "build" folder as a finished app.

// 1. LIBRARIES
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    $          = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    rimraf     = require('rimraf'),
    sequence   = require('run-sequence'),
    path       = require('path'),
    modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite'),
    router     = require('./bower_components/foundation-apps/bin/gulp-dynamic-routing');

// 2. SETTINGS VARIABLES
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// Sass will check these folders for files when you use @import.
var sassPaths = [
  'client/assets/scss',
  'bower_components/foundation-apps/scss'
];
// These files include Foundation for Apps and its dependencies
var foundationJS = [
  'bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js',
  'bower_components/viewport-units-buggyfill/viewport-units-buggyfill.js',
  'bower_components/tether/tether.js',
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/vendor/**/*.js',
  'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/**/*.js',
  '!bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/app.js'
];
// These files are for your app's JavaScript
var appJS = [
  'client/assets/js/app.js'
];

// 3. TASKS
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// Cleans the build directory
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf('./build', cb);
});

// Copies user-created files and Foundation assets
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  var dirs = [
    './client/**/*.*',
    '!./client/templates/**/*.*',
    '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'
  ];

  // Everything in the client folder except templates, Sass, and JS
  gulp.src(dirs, {
    base: './client/'
  })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));

  // Iconic SVG icons
  gulp.src('./bower_components/foundation-apps/iconic/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/img/iconic/'));

  // Foundation's Angular partials
  return gulp.src(['./bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/components/**/*.html'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/components/'));
});

// Compiles Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('client/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.rubySass({
      loadPath: sassPaths,
      style: 'nested',
      bundleExec: true
    })).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    })
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie 10']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/css/'));
});

// Compiles and copies the Foundation for Apps JavaScript, as well as your app's custom JS
gulp.task('uglify', function() {
  // Foundation JavaScript
  gulp.src(foundationJS)
    .pipe($.uglify({
      beautify: true,
      mangle: false
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe($.concat('foundation.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'))
  ;

  // App JavaScript
  return gulp.src(appJS)
    .pipe($.uglify({
      beautify: true,
      mangle: false
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});

// Copies your app's page templates and generates URLs for them
gulp.task('copy-templates', ['copy'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./client/templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(router({
      path: 'build/assets/js/routes.js',
      root: 'client'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/templates'))
  ;
});

// Starts a test server, which you can view at http://localhost:8080
gulp.task('server:start', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: './build',
    port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
    livereload: false
  });
});

// Builds your entire app once, without starting a server
gulp.task('build', function() {
  sequence('clean', ['copy', 'sass', 'uglify'], 'copy-templates', function() {
    console.log("Successfully built.");
  })
});

// Default task: builds your app, starts a server, and recompiles assets when they change
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'server:start'], function() {
  // Watch Sass
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/scss/**/*', './scss/**/*'], ['sass']);

  // Watch JavaScript
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/js/**/*', './js/**/*'], ['uglify']);

  // Watch static files
  gulp.watch(['./client/**/*.*', '!./client/templates/**/*.*', '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'], ['copy']);

  // Watch app templates
  gulp.watch(['./client/templates/**/*.html'], ['copy-templates']);
});
```

When I deploy, the app successfully build with one exception:

```
> gulp
> foundation-apps-template@1.0.3 start /app
[22:41:04] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
[22:41:04] Starting 'clean'...
[22:41:04] Starting 'build'...
[22:41:04] Starting 'server:start'...
[22:41:04] Starting 'default'...
[22:41:04] Finished 'server:start' after 323 ms
[22:41:04] Server started http://localhost:23921
[22:41:04] Finished 'build' after 343 ms
[22:41:04] Finished 'default' after 40 ms
[22:41:04] Starting 'sass'...
[22:41:04] Finished 'clean' after 386 ms
[22:41:04] Starting 'copy'...
State changed from starting to up
[22:41:05] Starting 'uglify'...
{ [Error: spawn bundle ENOENT]
   showProperties: true,
   errno: 'ENOENT',
   message: 'spawn bundle ENOENT',
   code: 'ENOENT',
   syscall: 'spawn bundle',
   path: 'bundle',
   plugin: 'gulp-ruby-sass' }
   name: 'Error',
   stack: 'Error: spawn bundle ENOENT\n    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)\n    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)\n    at child_process.js:1137:20\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)',
   showStack: false,
 [22:41:08] Finished 'sass' after 3.64 s
 [22:41:08] Finished 'uglify' after 3.28 s
 Successfully built.
```

After that, when I open the browser, I see the website, without CSS styles.

https://fierce-escarpment-9048.herokuapp.com/assets/css/app.css
404 Not Found

I suspect that - because of that exception with sass - the CSS file was not generated and - therefore - is not reachable to the server.

Any suggestion how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The specific errors you have posted actually relate to JavaScript, and most likely server-side JavaScript in the form of Node.js.  The "ENOENT" is specific to errors reported from Node.js' libuv component ( https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/include/uv.h ), and as you can see from the provided link relates to "no such file or directory".

So, your problem from the error logs/gulpfile.js is that the 'default' action initiates the task comprising of concurrent actions 'build' and 'server-start' (gulpfile.js, line 144). The 'build' task itself is a function (line 137) that initiates a sequence starting with 'clean' (line 138) to which we should return.  But first, 'server-start'... your server does start: "Starting 'server:start'... Finished 'server:start' after 323 ms... Server started http://localhost:23921...State changed from starting to up." So, you can see the matching output of "Starting [x]... Finished [x]" pairs captured in the logs.  This is significant.

Returning to the 'build' task. That causes 'clean', followed by the concurrent actions of 'copy', 'sass' and 'uglify'; it is within this latter group that your problem occurred. Firstly, note we have "Starting 'clean'... Finished 'clean' after 386 ms" - again, we have the matched pair - and clean must occur before copy/sass/uglify.  These are concurrent actions, and your problem is that the logged output is written apparently haphazardly as these tasks occur (thats true of the original overlapping build and start-server tasks too).  So, we can see all of 'copy', 'sass' and 'uglify' start... but only 'sass' and 'uglify' finish!  And, we have 'copy' start, and an otherwise unmatched/disassociated error message. Your error has arisen from the failure to 'copy', not from 'sass'!  You failed to copy, and the (Node.js-based) server was raising "no such file or directory".
Sorry, I couldn't interpret what its failed to copy (perhaps content from the 'client' directory), but its concerning absent content - perhaps even a simple misspelt filename, or something very similar.  You should probably examine closely the file content in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/25945-deploy-foundation-for-apps-to-heroku-using-rack) guide where explains how to deploy a Foundation for apps to heroku, I already tried it and works like a charm. Hope it helps.